# Mobilenet Original Paper Architecture vs Keras Implementation

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence

**1. Question: Why do original paper mobilenet architecture and keras implementation differ?**

Keras implementation of mobilenet's last 5 layers after AVG Pool layer:

```
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
    global_average_pooling2d_1 ( (None, 1024)              0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 1, 1, 1024)        0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1, 1, 1024)        0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv_preds (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 1, 1000)        1025000   
    _________________________________________________________________
    act_softmax (Activation)     (None, 1, 1, 1000)        0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 1000)              0
```

In the original Mobilenet paper, last 2 layers after AVG Pool layer look like this:

```
Type / Stride | Filter Shape | Input Size
Avg Pool / s1 | Pool 7 × 7   | 7 × 7 × 1024
FC / s1       | 1024 × 1000  | 1 × 1 × 1024
Softmax / s1  | Classifier   | 1 × 1 × 1000
```

**2. Question:** 
In the original paper, for the fully-connected layer, is there just 1 Input and 1 Output layer (with softmax) or is there also a hidden layer. I wasn't sure because they have mentioned Softmax as a separate layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convolutional layer with 1x1xC input shape and 1x1xC' output shape is equivalent to a fully connected layer. The architectures are the same.

A "softmax layer" typically means a linear layer followed by softmax activation. There is no additional hidden layer.

Comment: According to my understanding, 1x1 convolution is equivalent to a fully-connected layer when the input size is also 1x1xC. Would it be also equivalent to a fully-connected layer when the input size is lets say 32x32xC again with the kernel size 1x1xC?

Comment: a kernel is a 4D tensor HxWxCxC'. but no, in general unless the input or output have $H=W=1$, it's usually not a fully connected layer.